# how to combine two data csv in one file using python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

i have two data csv

The first:

```
v1,v2,v3,....v100
-0.6662942866484324,-1.0799718232204516,1.843649258216222,....1.0950462520122528
0.7452152929104426,-0.6032845087431591,0.7041161138126079,....-0.41362931908053513
```

The second:

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
4,1,0,0,1
14,2,2,0,13
```

when I combine using my code, the results are like this:

```
v1,v2,v3..v100,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
0.0,1.0,2,...0,0,0,1,0,0
```

my code is like this..

```
import pandas as pd
vector = pd.read_csv('../data/vector_data.csv',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
cluster= pd.read_csv('../data/data_cluster.csv',encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
data=vector.merge(cluster, left_on='v1', right_on='c1')
export_csv = data.to_csv (r'../data/merge_label.csv',index=False)
```

the result should be like this

```
v1,v2,v3..v100,c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
-0.6662942866484324,-1.0799718232204516,1.843649258216222,....1.0950462520122528,4,1,0,0,1
```

please help me...

Comment: What was your code that you tried?

Comment: I've edited it, look again

Answer (score 1):

#### Pandas not needed

```
with open('third.csv', 'w') as fh:
    for f, s in zip(*map(open, ['first.csv', 'second.csv'])):
        fh.write(f.rstrip('\n') + ',' + s)
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use pandas in this use-case?

Comment: If the application is to just merge csv files, importing pandas might be too much overhead.  Imagine this in a command line tool and needed to be run many times.  It just isn't necessary to load up a heavy hitting data analytics library to do something this simple.

Comment: Thanks as always, you are a great teacher.

Comment: Now i know what you meant :)

Answer (score 0):

try updating to this:

```
data=vector.merge(cluster, left_on='v1', right_on='c1', how='outer')
```

default is how=inner so looks like the only intersection may be 0 and creating the single row you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following code if it works:

```
data=pd.concat([vector,cluster],axis=1)
```